# How do I get sim number from my phone programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I have gone through all the links available on sto.

```
private String getMyPhoneNumber(){
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
}

private String getMy10DigitPhoneNumber(){
    String s = getMyPhoneNumber();
    return s.substring(2);
}
```

But most of the cases it returns null.
Is it impossible to trace phone number from telephony manager in Android or is there any other way out.

Comment: There is no safe way of retrieving the phone number. Sometimes works, some doesnt, depends on the sim card, network, etc... The best way to go at this is to simply ask the user for the number.

Comment: I've posted an answer please take a look.

Comment: @ShifarShifz OP is automatically notified of new answers on his questions, no need for an additional comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file please add below line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Also in java file add these lines:

```
 TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
    String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample on how to get SimSerial and other things.

```
            // Collecting device details
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) c
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            String model = android.os.Build.MODEL;
            String brand = android.os.Build.BRAND;

            String id = tm.getDeviceId();
            String simSerial = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
            String simCountry = tm.getSimCountryIso();
            String simOperator = tm.getSimOperatorName();
            String networkCountry = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

but getting phone number is impossible but i've found a small solution
    //Return user phone number
        public String getUserPhone(){

```
        AccountManager mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(mContext);
        Account[] mAccounts = mAccountManager.getAccounts();

        for(Account mAccount:mAccounts){

                Log.d("X","name:"+mAccount.name);
                Log.d("X","type:"+mAccount.type);

            if(isPhoneValid(mAccount.name)){
                return mAccount.name;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isPhoneValid(String phone) {
          boolean retval = false;
          String phoneNumberPattern = 
          "(\\d-)?(\\d{3}-)?\\d{3}-\\d{4}";
          retval = phone.matches(phoneNumberPattern);
          String msg = "NO MATCH: pattern:" + phone
          + "\r\n regex: " + phoneNumberPattern;
          if (retval) {
             msg = " MATCH: pattern:" + phone 
             + "\r\n regex: " + phoneNumberPattern;
          }
          System.out.println(msg + "\r\n");
          return retval;
       }
```

You have to set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

to play with Accounts.

As you can see i am collecting phone number from account, this works only if the user has WhatsApp,Telegram or anything like that on his/her phone. So i used to ask phone number manually if the above method [getUserPhone()] return null.

Comment: Telephony manger returns null ,i have already given permisssion.and for the account solution it is returning "watsapp" ..just ,,there is no number.

Comment: Can you put some Log in the loop that i used to get Phone Number,  and paste it here.